# Why doesn't the extglob "+(*/)A" work like "find -name A"?

Tags: bash

It seems like +(*/) in bash with extglob means something else than "(any char  sequence followed by a /) repeated a positive number of times"

```
$ find -name A
./a/A
./b/c/A
./b/A
$ echo */A
a/A b/A
$ echo */*/A
b/c/A
$ echo +(*/)A
+(*/)A
```

I thought that since the path to ./b/c/A matches the regex '([a-zA-Z1-9]*/)+[a-zA-Z1-9]*' it will be expanded to by +(*/)A but it isn't. What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern matches strings in the current directory. So the `+(*/)A` matches files or directories *in current directory* that match that pattern.

The pattern is invalid. As the `/` is not a valid character for a filename or a directory name. So the `+(*/)A` will never match anything, as the `/` will never match a filename.

You can use double `**` to match directories recursively. Or use `find`.

Comment: Then why did ```*/*/A``` match something not in the directory?

Comment: I don't understand. The `/` is the separator. The first `*` matches anything in the current directory. Then `/` as the separator. Then `*` matches anything in the second directory. The `+(*/)A` may be interpreted as directory `+(*` and filename `)A`. But bash is too stupid for that. And it's just the same as `**`.  Once bash sees `+( ... )` it interprets the whole as part of the filename. I guess it should throw some kind of error, like `syntax error: the '/' cannot be part of a filename in '+(*/)A'`